# Flutter Web Stuck at White Screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-web, flutter-test

When I Build Final Flutter Web Project then when i run this project on Chrome using Xampp this is stuck at White Screen Does Not Show Anything.  While When I am run this in debugging mode this works perfectly..  Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean the previous build using `flutter clean`.
2. run `flutter build web --release`.
3. check if it is running properly in release mode using `flutter run --release`,
   Select your browser here.
4. use your build from your_project/build/web.